# Spring Form - using Date and Time as input type to be assigned to a LocalDate and LocalTime variable. typeMismatch issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following spring form

```
<form:form action="/management/recruitment/setInterview" modelAttribute="interview">
Date<form:input type="Date" path="interviewDate"/><br>
Time<form:input type="Time" path="interviewTime"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Invite for interview" id="submitButton" />
```

- How can I make it send a LocalDate/Time object?
- Is this good practice, if not what would be a better way?

P.S.
I am using
java.time.LocalDate and LocalTime and my both variables are annotated with @DateTimeFormat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotate your `interviewDate` and `interviewTime` fields in the interview POJO with [DateTimeFormat](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html), like so:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
private LocalDate interviewDate;
```

Note that if the submitting date or time String from the user isn't in [DateTimeFormat.ISO](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html) format you can give it a custom pattern, such as `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")`

One other way to do this is to use an `@InitBinder` in the controller ([example](http://visionjava1.appspot.com/content/spring-mvc-initbinder-regiter-custom-date-editor-to-parse-date-from-form.html)), but for something as simple as this `DateTimeFormat` should be enough.

Comment: Regarding this. Will the @DateTimeFormat take any format? If `interviewTime` will be HH:mm, will this still work? I am asking because I have created converters for now as a workaround.

Comment: I believe using `pattern = "HH:mm"` should format it correctly, yes.